# Double Error Message In Google Sheet Form Made Using App Script

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

```
<!-- Button HTML -->
  <div class="container-btn">
    <div id="btnSearch" class="btn" onclick="notifySearch()"> <p> Search </p> </div>
    <div id="btnSave" class="btn" onclick="notifySave()">Save</div>
    <div id="btnUpdate" class="btn" onclick="notifyUpdate()"> <p> Update </p> </div>
    <div id="btnDelete" class="btn" onclick="notifyDelete()"> <p> Delete </p> </div>
  </div>
<!-- Notification CSS -->
```

This is some button

```
<style>
  #notification-area
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    color: ;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    z-index: -1;
}

#notification-area .notification
{
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #111;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}

#notification-area .notification.success
{
    background: #389838;
}

#notification-area .notification.error
{
    background: #ff4500;
}

#notification-area .notification.info
{
    background: #00acee;
}
</style>
```

This is CSS of notification

```
<!-- Notification HTML-->
<div id="notification-area">
  <!-- <div class="notification success">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
  <div class="notification error">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
  <div class="notification info">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div> -->
</div>
</body>
```

This is HTML Of notification

```
<!-- Save Dữ Liệu JS-->
<script>
  let notificationShown = false;
  const btnSave = document.getElementById("btnSave");
  btnSave.addEventListener("click", attempData);

  function attempData() {
    if (notificationShown)
    {
      return; // Nếu thông báo đã xuất hiện, không thực hiện thêm
    }
    const inputUser = document.getElementById("input-user").value;
    const inputWeek = document.getElementById("input-week").value;
    const inputItemCode = document.getElementById("input-ItemCode").value;
    const inputVendorCutting = document.getElementById("input-VendorCutting").value;
    const inputCuttingNumber = document.getElementById("input-CuttingNumber").value;
    const inputReleaseDate = document.getElementById("input-ReleaseDate").value;
    const inputAssemblingDate = document.getElementById("input-AssemblingDate").value;
    const inputRunningDate = document.getElementById("input-RunningDate").value;
    const inputCompletionDate = document.getElementById("input-CompletionDate").value;
    const inputVendorNote = document.getElementById("input-VendorNote").value;
    if (inputUser.length == 0 || inputWeek.length == 0 || inputItemCode.length == 0)
    {
      notifySave();
      notificationShown = true; // Đánh dấu rằng thông báo đã xuất hiện
    } 
    else
    {
      const data =
      {
        user: inputUser,
        week: inputWeek,
        itemCode: inputItemCode,
        vendorCutting: inputVendorCutting,
        cuttingNumber: inputCuttingNumber,
        releaseDate: inputReleaseDate,
        assemblingDate: inputAssemblingDate,
        runningDate: inputRunningDate,
        completionDate: inputCompletionDate,
        vendorNote: inputVendorNote
      };
      google.script.run.attempData(data);
      clearInputFields();
    }
  }

  function clearInputFields()
  {
    // Hàm xóa trường nhập liệu
    document.getElementById("input-user").value = "";
    document.getElementById("input-week").value = "";
    document.getElementById("input-ItemCode").value = "";
    document.getElementById("input-VendorCutting").value = "";
    document.getElementById("input-CuttingNumber").value = "";
    document.getElementById("input-ReleaseDate").value = "";
    document.getElementById("input-AssemblingDate").value = "";
    document.getElementById("input-RunningDate").value = "";
    document.getElementById("input-CompletionDate").value = "";
    document.getElementById("input-VendorNote").value = "";

    notificationShown = false; // Đánh dấu rằng thông báo đã được xử lý và có thể hiển thị lại
  }
</script>
```

This code use for save data and clear form

```
<!-- Notification JS -->
<script>
function notify(type,message)
{
  (() => 
  {
      let n = document.createElement("div");
      let id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,10);
      n.setAttribute("id",id);
      n.classList.add("notification",type);
      n.innerText = message;
      document.getElementById("notification-area").appendChild(n);
      setTimeout(() => 
      {
          var notification = document.getElementById("notification-area").getElementsByClassName("notification");
          for(let i = 0; i < notification.length; i++)
          {
              if(notification[i].getAttribute("id") == id)
              {
                  notification[i].remove();
                  break;
              }
          }
      },6000);
  })();
}

function notifySave() {
  if (!notificationShown) {
    notify("success", "Vui Lòng Nhập ÍT Nhất Trường User, Week And Item Code");
    notificationShown = true;
  }
}
</script>
```

This is Notification JAva Script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo0Eq.png)

I want a message just show once`

the first time i do it, it appear with 1 message but the data can't input in google form

when i tried to use browser.messagebox( notthing heppen)

finally, i can iput and show a error messgae but it show two times

This is my google sheet file of code
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qSJcndpa6NKkV0UlX--wfpikBacl0T2MWIY2wLQl6lQ/edit?usp=sharing